# LibreOffice Calc: Access a user selected range in a macro

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I'm looking to convert a MS Excel Spreadsheet into a LibreOffice Calc Spreadsheet.

The Excel file contains a VBA Macro that iterates over a range of cells selected by the user, the Visual Basic code simply looking like this:

```
For Each Value In Selection
    ' Manipulate Value
Next Value
```

Where `Selection` contains the cells in the worksheet manually selected by the user.

So, my question is: how can I reproduce this, accesing a user selected range of cells, in Libre Basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the value of the cells

```
Sub Learn
    Dim myController as Object, myRange as Object
    Dim Tmp as Integer
    Dim i, j

    myController = ThisComponent.getCurrentController()
    myRange = myController.getSelection().getDataArray()

    'additional info that we can use
    print myRange.AbsoluteName
    print myRange.RangeAddress.StartColumn
    print myRange.RangeAddress.StartRow

    Tmp = 0
    For Each i in myRange
        For Each j in i
            Tmp = Tmp + j
        Next j
    Next i
    print Tmp
End Sub
```

If you want to manipulate the cell's value, use a 2 dimensional array

```
Sub Learn2
    Dim myController as Object, myRange as Object
    Dim newRange(0, 0)
    Dim Tmp as Integer
    Dim i, j, col, row

    myController = ThisComponent.getCurrentController()
    myRange = myController.getSelection().getDataArray()
    Redim newRange(UBound(myRange, 1), UBound(myRange(0), 1))
    row = 0
    col = 0
    For row = 0 to UBound(myRange, 1)
        For col = 0 to UBound(myRange(0), 1)
            newRange(row, col) = myRange(row)(col) * 2
        Next col
    Next row
    myController.getSelection().setDataArray(newRange)
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks so complex compared to the 3 line VBA macro! Ouch.

Comment: @remi Please note that the example VBA Macro has a comment line "Manipulate Value" :) that line can easily grow if we want to really do something.

Comment: May I say with regards to the solution, if you really do want to print the AbsoluteName, then do it like this...
print ```ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getSelection().AbsoluteName```
and NOT like this....
```print ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getSelection().getDataArray().AbsoluteName```   i.e. drop the getDataArray()  part.
(LibreOffice 7.6.3.2)

Comment: Also, to get the column position of the selection {by number}  (A=0, B=1, C=2 etc) use ```print ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getSelection().RangeAddress.StartColumn```